# Changing the boolean value of an object stored in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm just starting my journey with JS so pleace be patient :)
I'm building a small app. The images on the left side are stored in an array. If someone clicks one of them I want to change its height but also the boolean value from false to true so that I know which one the user clicked (for further purposes). In my mind it goes like this: creating an array->add EventListener to the item->chain it witch the function choosen(change the value to true)->run setClick function that changes the height. What's wrong there?
I aprecciate any advice.
CODEPEN     `http://codepen.io/finewitch/pen/ZBKMKm`

```
    var storage = new Array();
storage[0] = document.getElementById("grandFatherCh");
storage[1] = document.getElementById("grandMotherCh");
storage[2] = document.getElementById("sisterCh");
storage[3] = document.getElementById("brotherCh");
storage[4] = document.getElementById("fatherCh");
storage[5] = document.getElementById("motherCh");
storage[0].clicked = false;
storage[1].clicked = false;
storage[2].clicked = false;
storage[3].clicked = false;
storage[4].clicked = false;
storage[5].clicked = false;


for (var i=0; i<storage.length; i++){
  storage[i].addEventListener("click",choosen, setClick);
  console.log("clicked");
};

function choosen(){
        if (storage[i].clicked == false) 
           {  
             return "stillFalse" 
          storage[i].clicked = true;        
    }

};

function setClick(){
  if(storage[i].clicked === true){
    return "setClickWorks"
    storage[i].style.height = "400px";
  }else{
   console.log('failed');
  }

};
```

Comment: You cannot just like that add a property to an element. `storage[0].clicked` - I believe it is a `HTMLElement` type and I don't think it has a built-in `clicked` property.

Comment: how would you like to click on an array in javascript? try binding an click eventhandler on an html element like @PraveenKumar suggested.

Comment: What's `setClick`? Also it should be `false` in the second argument of `addEventListener`

Comment: @PraveenKumar How can I add this property to each item in the array? using for loop?

Comment: @KevinKloet I added an EventListener isn't the same as eventHandler?

Comment: Can you share us the full code in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sigunadufu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: im trying to work with what says here:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-way-to-determine-which-image-has-been-clicked-that-is-stored-in-an-array-in-Javascript 
but still can't get it right. The're always two errors: "clicked not defined" or it treat all items as they were already clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but I think you have the return statement in the wrong place no? Should be

```
function choosen(){
  if (storage[i].clicked == false) {  
       return "stillFalse" 
  } else {
      storage[i].clicked = true;        
   } 
}

function setClick(){
  if (storage[i].clicked === true){
       storage[i].style.height = "400px";
       return "setClickWorks"
  } else {
      console.log('failed');
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, probobly you're right. But that's not the solution.